# Azure App Service "Has Encountered an Error String Match Failed. String Not Found"

Tags: php, azure, azure-app-service-plans

We're hosting a php website on `Azure App Service`. 
Sometimes it is down and displays this error:

> "Has Encountered an Error String Match Failed. String Not Found"

After restarting the App Service it works again. I'm quite sure it has nothing to do with the PHP part of it. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything helpful.

Why does it happen and how can we fix it?

Comment: Maybe not with Azure. [Check Azure common errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what MS Support wrote

> The application site content is hosted within Web App Azure App Services are backed by Azure Storage in a durable manner.  The application accesses the site contents as file shares to allow for application compatibility and availability. Unfortunately, there have been a few cases in which sites are unable to access their content, due to storage being unavailable via our file servers. The causes for this may include transient storage/network availability blips, file server maintenance (rebooting/OS patching) or even crashes.

Possible "fixes":

> - Use the Local cache feature.
> - Upgrade the service plan to premium V2, it is using SSD storage, and have faster speed to read and write.
> - Using VM to host website.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Always-on feature is ON and that PHP version is correctly set on the Portal.

Try enabling logging. To do this:

Use Kudu Console and go into D:\home\site\wwwroot

In your .user.ini file, add the following line (you can type touch .user.ini to create the file if it doesn't exist, and don't forget the starting dot on the .user.ini file!):

log_errors = On
Restart your site

Make a few failing requests to get some logging going.
Now, from Kudu Console, go to D:\home\LogFiles and open up (or download) php_errors.log.
At the end, you'll find the most recent entries, which may give clues as to what's going on.
Reference:https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Troubleshooting-PHP-errors